# Show Map control in a full screen mode

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

Is there any way to display a map in full screen on a Windows Phone 7.1 app ?
If I try to do this, there is black strips on top and on bottom on my map.

thanks for help

Comment: Sure It's possible. Remove margins around your maps control and hide titlebar

Comment: @flow Though the Windows Phone tags are a little more laid back it would be appreciated that if you have a question, please post what you have tried along with it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To show map in full mode, ensure that it has no margins and that is either the only element on the page or that the entire parent chain contains no `Padding` nor `Margin` properties. Also, set `shell:SystemTray.IsVisible` to `False` or set its opacity to something less than 1.
Same for `ApplicationBar`, either remove it or set its opacity to something less than 1.

What device are you running your application on? Are you running on HTC 8X or ATIV, those black bars cannot be removed.